# What is the earliest source that brings the custom to light bonfires on Lag Baomer?

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, lag-ba-omer

I've seen the reason of The Bnei Yisaschar (Iyar 3:3) that writes that there were many hidden secrets revealed on Lag Baomer that lit up the world, and we therefore light fires as a remembrance of the light of his Torah.

> ובזה תבין מנהג ישראל תורה היא להדליק נרות ומאורות ביום הזה לכבוד האור
> כי טוב שמתחיל להתנוצץ ביום זה היקר ל"ג בעמר טוב ימים קודם מתן תורה.
> ולכבוד נשמת מאיר התור' בוצינא קדישא אשר נתגלה ביום הזה וביום הזה עלה
> לשמי מרומים. והוא יומא דהילולא דילי' לאורו ניסע ונלך. לכבוד ספרו הקדוש
> זוהר המאיר ומבהיק מסוף העולם ועד סופו (אשר כתב ר' אבא ביום הזה) והוא
> מאיר לנו בגלותינו עד כי יבא משיח צדקינו דאתמר בי' ויאמר אלקים יה"י אור
> (בגימ' ע"ב ס"ג מ"ה ב"ן) זה אורו של מלך המשיח יבא ב"ב ויגלה לנו האור
> הגנוז. והמשכילים יזהירו כזה"ר הרקיע ותבין לפי"ז אשר נתאמת לנו מאנשי
> אמת אשר השמח' ביום הזה על ציון רשב"י היא שלא כטבע דכתיב אור צדיקים
> ישמח

Are there any earlier sources for this?